# Strange Copy Pattern to External Drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Typically when I copy over files to an external drive in Windows, the GUI that results goes up to a peak, and stays relatively stable till the end of the transfer. But with my HDD my files tend to transfer like below:

[image]

What's causing the random start-stop behavior? The HDD is connected via a SATA to USB 3.0 connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the large number of files (~5000) and the size of the files.  When you copy a file it is read from the disk, goes into memory in the file system cache then is written to the destination. Reading and writing to physical media is slow, however actions from the cache which is is memory are fast.  This is why there are lots of peaks and valleys.

As for why it appears to stop, there could be a lot of reasons.  The cache is constantly being filled and emptied, slowdowns will occur with very large files.  Antivirus programs, if installed, are looking at every file that is being copied.  With that many files, the AV probably is having a hard time keeping up with the transfer and is slowing down the speed of the copy.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Because I was getting ~110 MB/s woth a large file vs the <10 with many files